# How do I remove the Alt functionality in Google Chrome so that when I press Alt, it doesn't start navigating the 3 dots symbol at the top right?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

When typing in a Google document inside of Google Chrome sometimes I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate between the windows and it's 50% chance that instead of tabbing somewhere else in Windows with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it does this thing where it navigates inside the 3 dot symbol at the top right and I get stuck in it where the settings are and then I can't continue my typing.

It's an absolute nightmare for typing out pages so I'm wondering if there's a possible way to remove the "Alt" function so that when pressed, it doesn't press on the 3 dot symbol at the top right of the Google chrome?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no functionality provided by Google to disable keyboard shortcuts.
There are extensions like Hotkey, shortcut manager and [Keyboard-fu](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-fu/cafiohcgicchdfciefpbjjgigbmajndb) which provides User Defined shortcuts though.
Seems shortcut manager doesn't exist anymore.

You may also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637530/disable-shortcuts-in-google-chrome), for deep customization of hardcoded shortcuts you will need some coding.

For further reference visit:

[Change/Disable Chrome Keyboard shortcuts](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/NTXSjYQUPG4)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone reading this in the future:
one way to work around this is to make a AutoHotkey script that auto-presses the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key every time <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed and Chrome is selected.